# How do we access the .class file in java equivalent in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

In android the same way we access JavaFile.class, how do we do that in Kotlin?

Comment: This will help you https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you really referring to a class file, or are you talking about the **type** SomeClass.class within java source code?

Comment: `YourClass::class.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the Kotlin class:

```
SomeType::class
```

To access the underlying Java class:

```
SomeType::class.java
// or
SomeType::javaClass
```